# I can't get a list of dialogs by folder id (telethon)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to get all the dialogs from the "People" folder with ID 3, but I can't.

```
async def get_users_response(client, users):
    dialogs = await client.get_dialogs(folder=3)
    for dialog in dialogs:
        print(dialog)
```

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FolderIdInvalidError: The folder you tried to use was not valid (caused by GetDialogsRequest)

If you display all the folders in Telegram with this code

```
async def get_folders(client):
    result = await client(functions.messages.GetDialogFiltersRequest())
    for x in result:
        print(x)
```

> DialogFilterDefault()
> DialogFilter(id=3, title='People', pinned_peers=[], include_peers=[], exclude_peers=[], contacts=True, non_contacts=True, groups=False, broadcasts=False, bots=False, exclude_muted=False, exclude_read=False, exclude_archived=False, emoticon='')

We can see that the folder with id 3 exists, what could be the problem?
I use Telethon==1.27.0

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Telegram has them designed, if peers=[] and other lists are empty, it means it's a generic pre-defined folder by chat type, like groups, channels and contact + non-contacts in your case.

those aren't server-side, clients are expected to fetch all the dialogs and sort them locally.